# How to know what processes open TCP ports?

Tags: linux, netstat

I am using a Busybox distro and I don't have iptables. I would like to discover what processes open the ports: 8001 and 35292 to kill them and close that ports.

```
root@(none):/proc/1709/net# netstat -a | grep LISTEN
netstat: /proc/net/tcp6: No such file or directory
tcp        0      0 (null):8001             (null):*                LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 (null):rmiregistry      (null):*                LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 (null):ssh              (null):*                LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 (null):35292            (null):*                LISTEN
```

Many thanks in advance

Doubt solved with the parameter -p:

```
root@(none):~# netstat -a -p
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 (null):8001             (null):*                LISTEN      1527/java
tcp        0      0 (null):8002             (null):*                LISTEN      1527/java
tcp        0      0 (null):56618            (null):*                LISTEN      1527/java
tcp        0      0 (null):rmiregistry      (null):*                LISTEN      1527/java
tcp        0      0 (null):ssh              (null):*                LISTEN      1181/dropbear
tcp        0      0 (null):telnet           (null):*                LISTEN      1166/telnetd
tcp        0      0 (null):ssh              (null):55960            ESTABLISHED 1549/dropbear
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `man netstat` :

```
-p, --program
Show the PID and name of the program to which each socket belongs.
```

By adding the `-p` option, you'll get the PIDs of the programs listening. That's fairly enough to use `ps` afterwards :

```
ps -ef | grep [your-pid]
```

Not sure if your question is programming-specific though. I would recommend Unix & Linux, or Server Fault (among others).

Comment: Great! With that parameter, I could solve my doubt.